# How standardised are compilers' errors?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, standards, string-formatting

I am interested in automatically filtering and interpreting the error messages outputted by gcc and other compilers

For example this regex (which could be improved but you get the idea)

```
^(.+?):(\d+)(:(\d+))?:\s+(\w+):\s+(.*)$
```

Would capture the following gcc error

> x.cpp:5: error: expected initializer before 'std'

with

- `$1` = name of source
- `$2` = line number
- `$4` = column number (not all gcc versions)
- `$5` = category ("error" or "warning")
- `$6` = error text

What guarantees are made about the stability and portability of the string format between different versions of gcc? Any guarantees for other compilers?

Comment: None.  Zero.  I would even guess that there's nothing dictating compatibility of messages between different GCC/G++ versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guarantee - the Standard will say "the code is ill-formed" and the compiler will emit whatever error it decides.

Also don't forget that most C++ compiler don't even produce optimally crafted error messages - there's nothing to standardize at the moment. For example, if you write:

```
statement1 //no ;
statement2;
```

they will say `no ; before statement2` which is right, but not as convenient and useful as `no ; after statement1` would be. And error messages emitted when compiling templates are so horrible that there're even stand-alone prettifiers for them.

Comment: I'm not talking about the *content* of error messages, but their *form*.

Comment: @spraff: Their form will depend on implementation. For example, currently VC++10 emits some error messages twice for the same construct due to some defect in code. How can you be sure that your compiler doesn't have a defect that break message form for some errors?

Comment: Compiler faults are always Game Over. It's still possible that they could be TRYING to make life easy for people who are integrating with them

Comment: @spraff: I doubt they even try - they still don't have human-usable error messages.